# Liquibase runs changeset again when starting Spring boot application in debug in idea

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

when i start my spring boot application in the default run mode it executes the liquibase statement as normal.

Stopping and running again skips the changeset as normal, since it was already executed.

starting in debug mode however tries to execute the changeset again even though it ran already.

I turned it around and first executed the change in debug which neatly creates the entry in the databasechangelog
and when running it a second time in non debug mode the same happens

My changes are in native sql format, the database is mariadb with the mysql connector

I compared the md5 sum of both databasechangelog (run first vs debug first) entries and they are the same.

liquibase version is 3.5.4 I also tested 3.5.5 with the same result

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

here is also the logging part where liquibase fails

```
2018-05-01 13:54:00.610 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Connected to xxx@localhost@jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project1_db?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true
2018-05-01 13:54:00.610 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Setting auto commit to false from true
2018-05-01 13:54:00.642 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2018-05-01 13:54:00.647 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2018-05-01 13:54:00.648 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2018-05-01 13:54:00.649 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Lock Database
2018-05-01 13:54:00.655 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)', LOCKGRANTED = '2018-05-01 13:54:00.650' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0
2018-05-01 13:54:00.657  INFO 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
2018-05-01 13:54:00.672 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Opening file:/home/xxx/project1-connector/project1-backend/target/classes/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml as classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
2018-05-01 13:54:00.687 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : includeAll for db/changelog/changes/
2018-05-01 13:54:00.687 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Using file opener for includeAll: liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader)
2018-05-01 13:54:00.690 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Opening file:/home/xxx/project1-connector/project1-backend/target/classes/db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql as db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql
2018-05-01 13:54:00.690 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Opening file:/home/xxx/project1-connector/project1-backend/target/classes/db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql as db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql
2018-05-01 13:54:00.694 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Computed checksum for 1525175640693 as 422ae5f56810de3fc5eeb17bb4af5afe
2018-05-01 13:54:00.710 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: SELECT MD5SUM FROM project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2018-05-01 13:54:00.711 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOG
2018-05-01 13:54:00.712  INFO 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Reading from project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOG
2018-05-01 13:54:00.712 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Executing QUERY database command: SELECT * FROM project1_db.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2018-05-01 13:54:00.716 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Computed checksum for inputStream as 0c73ccd0174246a5a7fab00d26cc30d2
2018-05-01 13:54:00.720 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Computed checksum for 7:0c73ccd0174246a5a7fab00d26cc30d2: as 22c8e24ae058e8e523819972d470a98a
2018-05-01 13:54:00.721 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Running Changeset:db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx
2018-05-01 13:54:00.721 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Changeset db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx
2018-05-01 13:54:00.721 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Reading ChangeSet: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx
2018-05-01 13:54:00.727 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Executing Statement: insert into company (id, name, created_at, created_by)
values (1, 'mycompany', now(), 'xxx')
2018-05-01 13:54:00.728 DEBUG 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Executing EXECUTE database command: insert into company (id, name, created_at, created_by)
values (1, 'mycompany', now(), 'xxx')
2018-05-01 13:54:00.733 ERROR 27486 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx: Change Set db/changelog/changes/db.change.sql::basicdata::xxx failed.  Error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' [Failed SQL: insert into company (id, name, created_at, created_by)
values (1, 'mycompany', now(), 'xxx')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it could be the problem with `logicalFilePath`. Maybe your classpath is slightnly different in debug and in normal run. Try to specify it in your sql files. [look here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) for info.